# Java 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

so every time i run the program and enter the 2nd choice, it tells me rangecheck error , index0 , size 0.

what i understand from this after research is that the arraylist is empty, how do i use the add function in the 2D arraylist?

|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX

--+------------------------

01|gggggggggggggggggggggggg

02|gGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGg

03|gGggggggggggggggggggggGg

04|gGgYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYgGg

05|gGgYggggggggggggggggYgGg

06|gGgYggggggggggggggggYgGg

07|gGgYggYYYYYYYYYYYYggYgGg

08|gGgYggYggggggggggYggYgGg

09|gGgYYYYggggggggggYYYYgGg

10|gGggggggggggggggggggggGg

11|gGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGg

12|gggggggggggggggggggggggg

```
package map;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapMain 
{
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        InputStream is = null;
          int i;
          char c;
          String T;
          ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Contain = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
          for(int L = 0; L < 30; L++)
          {
              Contain.add(new ArrayList<String>());
          }

          try{
              do{
            int a=0;
            String Elements;
            System.out.print("To load map enter 1\nTo print loded map enter 2\nTo change specific elements press 3  ");
            a=input.nextInt();
            switch (a){
            case 1 :
                System.out.print("What is the file dest?");
                T=input.nextLine();
                is = new FileInputStream(T);
                while((i=is.read())!=-1)
                {
                   c=(char)i;
                   String O = "ankosh";
                   //Contain.add(Contain.O);
                }
                break; 
            case 2:
                while(true)
                {
                   String U = Contain.get(16).get(0);
                   //System.out.print(Contain);
                   break;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("What do you want to insert?");
                Elements=input.nextLine();
                //switch (Elements){
                //case 
                }
                break;
            } while(true);
          }catch(Exception e){

        // if any I/O error occurs
        e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all, always use _camelCase_ for variable name

Comment: you need to get the first list and add on the second like Contain.get(0).add("this String"); Why are you using a double array list ? can't you use a map or something of that sort ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer could you provide an example or a source for a map?

Comment: @Ankosh please read on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html & implementation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html you should be able to find examples on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You created the array of arrays, and the arrays it contains, so far it's ok.
Now, on case 2 you are trying to reach the first element of the 16th array (basically of type String) which is null since you didn't add anything yet to this array.
What you need to do before trying the get(index), is to check that the length of the array is bigger than the index.
In order to add to the array:content.get(16).add(str);.

Comment: Okay so i added the element and it worked thank you!
had another question, i'm trying to load from a file into that ArrayList, so i want it in a table, now its like an array inside an array not an array[row][col] table, is it possible to have it in a table so the if the user wants , for example, to change Array[2][2] to input "Y"? because a lot of people told me to use HashMaps better @user265732

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible to have it in a table so the if the user wants , for example, to change Array[2][2] to input "Y"?"

Comment: well the switch cases one of them is to change specif elements in the array depending on the row and col the user provides. how do i refer the row and col from the user to the index in the arraylist?

Comment: Well, if you use array of arrays, you can refer Array[2][2] as the third string of the third array:         contain.get(2).set(2,"Y"); As I mentioned before, make sure that the index exists.

Comment: well the index would depend on how large the 2D array in the txt file actually is

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand- you are loading a text file, which you need to map? Letter in each cell?

Comment: Yes, its a basic archaeological map where symbols are findings.
and the map is written in a txt file and i need to load it into a 2D ArrayList.  but i'm trying first to understand at least the ArrayList.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62558/discussion-between-ankosh-and-user265732).